# How do I make a program from my C++ code?

Tags: c++

I found this code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
}
```

How do I run this code?
What software do I need?
How do I use that software to make a program?

I thought this would be a good faq for absolute beginners.  Each answer could provide detailed instructions for a particular compiler/environment.

Comment: I assume you are FAQing this?

Comment: I'm not so sure.  If this question came up on it's own, we'd probably say "post this on programmers.stackexchance.com" or close it as "off-topic."  But let the people decide.

Comment: Why does someone who's answered 100+ questions, mostly about C++, post a question like this?!?

Comment: @Paul:  PigBen is trying to construct a FAQ entry.

Comment: Removed from the `c++-faq` tag. Please [discuss](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/212892#212892) if you disagree.

Answer (score 3):

On most Linux/Unix machines, you will have a C++ compiler available, although you may need to have it installed.  The most used one is g++, which is part of the Gnu tools.

First, save the program you wrote with an extension like .cpp (there are others), so suppose you save it as `test.cpp`.

Then, to compile it, you'd type

```
g++ -o test test.cpp
```

at a minimum.  There's lots of options for g++, but we won't worry about them now.  This takes the program in file `test.cpp`, compiles it, and leaves the executable in `test`.  Therefore, to run it, type

```
./test
```

The reason for the `./` is fairly involved, but having to do that prefix avoids problems with security and with any conflict with system commands or other installed programs.

Answer (score 2):

**If you are on Windows and want to use the Microsoft Visual C++ IDE**

Purchase Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 here: http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/how-to-buy-vs#Fragment_BuyFromMSHeading

Or download the free Express version here: http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#DownloadFamilies_2 or http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#DownloadFamilies_4

Install and then start up the Application.

On the file menu, select 'New', then 'Project'.

In the left pane 'Installed Template', expand the list item 'Visual C++' and select the 'Win32' sub-item.

In the center pane, select 'Win32 Console Application'

At the bottom, type in the Name and select a directory location for your project.

Click 'OK'.  Click 'Next'.

Make sure 'Console application' under 'Application type' is selected.  Check the box 'Empty project'.

Click 'Finish'.

You've now created a project.  Now you need to add your code to it.

In the left pane 'Solution Explorer', you should see your project name with some folders under it.  Right-click on the one that says 'Source Files', select 'Add', then 'New Item'.

Find 'C++ File (.cpp)' in the list.  Give it a name at the bottom.  Click 'Add'.

Insert your code in the editor that is now showing.

F7 to build your program.

If your program built correctly, you can run it from within the editor by pressing Ctrl+F5.

Or you can navigate to your program.  If your project was named "MyProgram" for example, and the directory location you chose was "C:\Projects\", you can find the program at: "C:\Projects\MyProgram\Debug\MyProgram.exe"

Comment: If the question is "how do I compile my code?" then isn't it easier to explain "Open the Visual Studio Tools command prompt, browse to your file, and run `cl myfile.cpp`...

Comment: @James -- That would be a different development environment, so add another answer.

Comment: @James McNellis: Use a command prompt? On Windows? Are you mad??  ;v)

Comment: @Fred:  Very Petzold-ish.  Funny thing is that Petzold even uses the IDE these days.